# How to copy a certain part of text from one file to another in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

To extract a certain part of text
in this example I want to extract from d to f

input.txt contains:

```
a
d
c
b
e
f
g
a
a
```

the output.txt should contain from d to f
but this program copies from d to last line of input.txt file

```
f = open('input.txt')
f1 = open('output.txt', 'a')

intermediate_variable=False

for line in f:

    if 'd' in line:
        intermediate_variable=True
        if intermediate_variable==True:
            f1.write(line)

f1.close()
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it:

```
contents = open('input.txt').read()
f1.write(contents[contents.index("d"):contents.index("f")])
```

Comment: Add +1 to second index to capture the 'f', although not sure what OP meant by 'from d to f'.

Comment: @faridaamina if it helped you, please accent the answer

Answer (score 1):

There are more convenient ways to read and write files, this version uses a generator and the 'with' keyword (context manager) which automatically closes the file for you. Generators (functions with 'yield' are nice because they give you the file a line at a time, although you have to wrap their output in try/except block)

```
def reader(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            yield line

def writer(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'w') as fout:  #change 'w' to 'a' to append ('w' overwrites)
        fout.write(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = reader("input.txt")
    while True:
        try:
            temp = next(a)
            if 'd' in temp:
                #this version of above answer captures the 'f' as well
                writer("output.txt", temp[temp.index('d'):temp.index('f') + 1])
        except StopIteration:
            break
```

Comment: What's the point of defining your own reader/writer? `.read()` essentially does the same thing - line-wise reading. Same for `.write(line)`.

Comment: It's to avoid leaving file objects open unnecessarily, is how I think of it, and by using 'with' you never have to worry about manually calling .close(). Also, if you are reading and writing at many places in your program, it's convenient.

Answer (score 0):

straight forward:

```py
### load all the data at once, fine for small files:
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read().splitlines() ## use f.readlines() to have the newline chars included

### slice what you need from content:
selection = content[content.index("d"):content.index("f")]
## use content.index("f")+1 to include "f" in the output.

### write selection to output:
with open('output.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(selection))
    ## or:
    # for line in selection:
        # f.write(line + '\n')
```

Comment: @faridaamina, hope it helped, don't know why it got downvoted - see for yourself if it works.

Comment: not exactly
but anyhow fixed the problem learnt another way from you tanq

Comment: @faridaamina, alright, make sure to accept the answer that helped you the most.